# Asyncio Making HTTP Requests Slower?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, benchmarking, python-asyncio

I'm using Asyncio and Requests to benchmark a series of HTTP requests.

For some reason, it's slightly slower to use Asyncio than just straight Requests. Any idea why? Am I using Asyncio incorrectly?

```
import asyncio
import functools
import requests
import time

ts = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  @asyncio.coroutine
  def do_checks():
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      req = loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.get, "http://google.com", timeout=3))
      resp = yield from req
      print(resp.status_code)

  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(do_checks())
te = time.time()
print("Version A: " + str(te - ts))

ts = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  r = requests.get("http://google.com", timeout=3)
  print(r.status_code)
te = time.time()

print("Version B:  " + str(te - ts))
```

Output:

Version A = Asyncio; Version B = Requests

```
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
Version A: 5.7215821743011475
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
Version B:  5.320340156555176
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are waiting for each request to finish before you start the next one. So you have the overhead of the event loop with no benefits.

Try this:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import requests
import time

ts = time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@asyncio.coroutine
def do_checks():
    futures = []
    for i in range(10):
        futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.get, "http://google.com", timeout=3)))

    for req in asyncio.as_completed(futures):
        resp = yield from req
        print(resp.status_code)

loop.run_until_complete(do_checks())
te = time.time()
print("Version A: " + str(te - ts))

ts = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    r = requests.get("http://google.com", timeout=3)
    print(r.status_code)
te = time.time()
print("Version B:  " + str(te - ts))
```

This is what I get when i run it:

```
$ python test.py 
200
...
Version A: 0.43438172340393066
200
...
Version B: 1.6541109085083008
```

Much faster, but really this is just spawning threads and waiting for the http library to finish, you don't need `asyncio` to do that.

You might want to checkout `aiohttp` as it was built for use with `asyncio`. `requests` is a fabulous library, but it is not made for `asyncio`.

Comment: Great answer, that helps! Are there any advantages to having `asyncio` spawn threads instead of doing it directly?

Comment: @okoboko If you're going to use `requests`, there's really no need to use `asyncio`, unless you've got other components in your project that are actually designed for use with `asyncio`. And if that's the case, you should favor `aiohttp` over `requests`, unless you need a feature of `requests` that's missing from `aiohttp`.

Comment: One note with `loop.run_in_executor` - when you use the default executor (by passing `None` as the first argument), you're using a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` with five threads. That means you can only run five requests concurrently, which is pretty low for an I/O bound workload. You'll probably get better performance if you create your own ThreadPoolExecutor with more threads.

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness, here is a really fast asyncio implementation

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

async def main(n):
    ts = time.time()
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    fs = [session.get('http://google.com') for _ in range(n)]
    for f in asyncio.as_completed(fs):
        resp = await f
        print(resp.status)
        await resp.release()
    await session.close()
    te = time.time()
    print("Aiohttp version:  " + str(te - ts))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(10))
loop.close()
```

The code is python 3.5 and higher.

```bash
~> python asyncioreq.py
200
...
Aiohttp version:  0.15974688529968262
```

Hope somebody can use it ;)

Comment: await session.close() OR use it as context manager.
I got an error that session.close() was never awaited.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @brunsgaard's answer: you can go a step further with aiohttp and gathering your results with `asyncio.gather()`. You can then take the responses from your requests and handle them.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

async def main(n):
    start = time.time()
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    jobs = [session.get('http://google.com') for _ in range(n)]
    done_jobs = await asyncio.gather(*jobs)
    for done_job in done_jobs:
        print(done_job.status)
    session.close()
    end = time.time()
    print("Time:  " + str(end - start))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(10))
loop.close()
```

Comment: This is much cleaner way to achieve the goal. Should be the correct answer.